# Find the explicit form of $(f \circ g)(x)$ and specify its domains for $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ and $g(x)= \frac{1}{x-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Im a maths student studing for an upcoming real analysis test and I've been given this simple question. I'm hoping im on the right track but if I'm not any tips would be much appreciated!

First we establish $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x \neq 1$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x-2}$ for $x \neq 2$. The explicit form of

$$(f \circ g )(x) = \frac{\frac{1}{x-2}}{\frac{1}{x-2} +1 } = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

Therefore the domain of $(f \circ g)(x)$ is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x \neq 1\}$.

Thankyou for your time!

Comment: $x=2$ can't be part of the Domain, because you can't evaluate g(x). Also, $x\neq 1$ because $g(1) =-1$, and $-1$ is forbidden value for $f(x)$. 
Thus, the Domain is $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\ x\neq 1\ \wedge \ x\neq 2\}$

Comment: @Koro the values for $x$ are taken from the domain of $g(x)$, so $-1$ is valid

Comment: @FormerMath,But f is not defined at $x=-1$

Comment: I know, but when you construct the composite function $f\circ g$, the variable "x" is linked to the function $g$. After you compute the image $g(x)$ you have to decide if it is valid to evaluate that image in $f$. That's all about $f(g(x))$: $g$ is evaluated on $x$, and $f$ is evaluated on $g(x)$

Comment: @FormerMath, that is correct. I understand that for $fog$ to be defined, $g(x) \ne -1$ in this case since $-1$ is not in domain of $f$. But you mentioned in your earlier comment that - 1 is valid. No it is not. $g(x) \ne - 1 \implies x\ne 1$ so 1 is also not valid.

Comment: @Koro So I'm affraid there's a confusion. When I said "-1 is valid", it is because is a valid number to take in $Dom (f\circ g)$, because $g(-1) = -\frac{1}{3}$ and $f(-\frac{1}{3}) = -\frac{3}{4}$ I'm sorry if that causes confusion, it wasn't my intention.

Comment: @FormerMath, Thank you so much. I understood it now. $fog(x) =1/(x-1)$ and I was confusing $g(x) $ with $x$. $g(x) \ne - 1$ it's not that $fog$ is not defined at - 1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is put into $f$, we must ensure that $x$ is not equal to $2$ because that will make the denominator of $g$ equal to zero. Further, after subbing $g$ into $f$ we arrive at $\frac{1}{x-1}$ after simplifying (verify!) and so $x$ cannot be equal to $1$ either. So these two(!) $x$ values need to be excluded from the domain. Think about it: For $x=2$ we have the denominator of $g$ equal to zero and for $x=1$ function $g$ produces a value that makes the denominator of the COMPOSITION equal to zero. That's why there are 2 $x$ values to be excluded